# react native redux toolkit how can I pass data to array?

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, redux-toolkit

How can I pass data to array (redux toolkit) ?

I tried this but not working.

I have an array of shippers:

```
 const shipper = [
    {
      type: 'NORMAL',
      item: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'SHIPPER1',
      }
    },
    {
        type: 'NORMAL',
        item: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'SHIPPER2',
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'NORMAL',
      item: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'SHIPPER3',
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'NORMAL',
      item: {
        id: 4,
        name: 'SHIPPER4',
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'NORMAL',
      item: {
        id: 5,
        name: 'SHIPPER5',
      }
    },
];
```

I want to add each item to the reducer array. Like this without redux.

```
setShippers(prevState => {
  return [...prevState, shipper];
});
```

But I want it in Redux Toolkit:

slice/shipper.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const createProductShipper = createSlice({
  name: "createProductShipper",
  initialState: {
    shippers: []
  },
  reducers: {
    AddProductShipper(state, action) {
      state.shippers = [...state.shippers, action.payload];
    },

  }
});

export const { AddProductShipper } = createProductShipper.actions;

export default createProductShipper.reducer;
```

```
...
dispatch(AddProductShippers({id, shipper});
...
```

..................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: I can see no problem in your code. What does console.log(action.payload) print in AddProductShipper action?

Comment: The reducer looks fine.  The dispatch is potentially wrong, but it depends on the shape of your state.  Instead of dispatch(AddProductShippers({id, shipper})) you might want dispatch(AddProductShippers(shipper))

Answer (score 0):

I’m a bit confused about whether the shipper variable is an array or a single shipper — and I suspect that you are too.

Your “without redux” example would be the correct way to add a *single* shipper to the array.  If shipper is an array then you’ll want to spread both prevState and shipper:

```
setShippers(prevState => [...prevState, …shipper]);
```

The same goes for the redux reducer.

But the way that you are calling the dispatch seems strange:

```
dispatch(AddProductShippers({id, shipper}));
```

This will dispatch an action whose payload has properties id and shipper.  Is that what you want?  What is the id property: the product id or the shipper id?

Assuming that the product id is irrelevant (it appears nowhere in your slice) and that you want to add an array of shippers, your code might look something like this:

```
dispatch(AddProductShippers(arrayOfShippers));


AddProductShipper(state, action) {
  state.shippers = [...state.shippers, …action.payload];
}
```

Or

```
AddProductShipper(state, action) {
  state.shippers.push(…action.payload);
}
```